# shell scripting variables addition

Tags: shell, variables, scripting

If I have a variable as

`month=02` and when I add one to it as month=`expr $month + 1`
then it becomes `month=3` but I want it to be `month=03`  what shall I do for this?

even when I add

```
month=`expr $month + 01`
```

it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
$ month=1
$ printf "%02d" $month
01
```

This approach would work when `month` is double-digit number.

```
$ month=11
$ printf "%02d" $month
11
```

[You can also increment a variable by saying `let month++`.]